# What does the data communication flow look like during a Capistrano deployment? Is there a diagram somewhere that explains this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I couldn't find any information regarding how information flows during a Capistrano deployment, and I can't make out the log information when running the deployment.

I currently have the following setup:

1. Development code on my laptop
2. Local Git server
3. Staging web server

I push my code to the local Git server with the Capistrano repo_url set to the repository on this server. The code is then deployed to the staging web server. During the deployment, does the communication go like this:

1 --> 2 --> 3?

Or is there any communication from 1 (the development laptop) to 3 (the web server)?

Comment: Capistrano is a development tool which takes the repo from your GitHub and deploys it to production/staging server. Refer:     https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-capistrano-to-automate-deployments-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

this could help :

https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh

It's cleaning cap log while you're deploying, let you follow up capistrano work flow

"When you run cap, Capistrano dutifully connects to your server(s) via SSH and executes the steps necessary to deploy your project." This that your local code has nothing to do with it.

When you use cap staging deploy (for example). Capistrano will look about a staging.rb file for settings. Connect to your server and pull code from your github.

As I assume you're new with capistrano, take a look at  :

https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks

I'll help you to manage your db and staging/prod db for any tests/bug solving.

I hope this help :)